# sequelize findOne return null then model is empty

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a function which have to return config with activities of domains.

```
async function getConfig(configId, country) {
    return await db.config.findOne({
        where: { id: configId },
        include: [
            {
                model: db.domain,
                attributes: ['id', 'domain'],
                where: {
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    });
}
```

But I get an error `default - TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataValues' of undefined` because my table `domain` is empty but I want to get result

```
    "result": {
        "id": 4,
        "country": "US",
        "domains": []
    }
```

How can I do it?

Config model

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Config extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of DataTypes lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            Config.hasMany(models.domain, {
                foreignKey: 'configId',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            });
        }
    }

    Config.init(
        {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },
            country: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            tableName: 'configs',
            modelName: 'config',
            timestamps: false,
        },
    );
    return Config;
};
```

Domain model

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Domain extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of DataTypes lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            Domain.belongsTo(models.config, {
                foreignKey: 'configId',
            });
        }
    }

    Domain.init(
        {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },
            domain: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            isActive: {
                type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: false,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            tableName: 'domains',
            modelName: 'domain',
            timestamps: false,
        },
    );
    return Domain;
};
```

Comment: Can you include the model definitions? You are using the wrong kind of association.

Comment: You also don't have to `return await` because it's an async function so you can just return the promise.

Comment: @doublesharp I added my two models

Comment: Your associations are actually fine, the answer by Anatoly is correct about adding `required: false` to the include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to indicate `required: false` option like this:

```
return await db.config.findOne({
        where: { id: configId },
        include: [
            {
                required: false,
                model: db.domain,
                attributes: ['id', 'domain'],
                where: {
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    });
```

That way you say to Sequelize that you wish to get main model instances regardless of conditions in associated models.

If you familiar with SQL then it means to turn `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.